# Can anyone help me solve this for loop and if statements code?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

For my question, I've been given 3 if statements/conditions for the for loop code.

Question: Use the for loop and if control statements to list the women's non-empty home destinations `home.dest`, `age` 50 or older, who embarked from Southampton (S) on the Titanic, see `titanic` package.

I don't understand how to start the for loop statement where the `i` is defined. I'm also trying to skip printing empty cells of the home destination column.

This is what I've tried so far:

```r
for (i in 1) {
  if (titanicDataset$age[i] >= 50 & (titanicDataset$embarked[i] == "S") & titanicDataset$sex == "female")
  {(print(titanicDataset$home.dest[i]))}
  else if (i == "")
    next
}
```

issues

> Error in if (titanicDataset$age[i] >= 50 & (titanicDataset$embarked[i] ==  :
> the condition has length > 1

Comment: I guess `titanicDataset$sex` should be `titanicDataset$sex[i]`. And the loop should go over more values than just 1.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you are looking for

```r
library(titanic)
titanicDataset = titanic_test |> type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
titanicDataset = titanicDataset[complete.cases(titanicDataset), ]
for(i in seq_len(nrow(titanicDataset))) 
  if(titanicDataset$Age[[i]] >= 50 & titanicDataset$Embarked[[i]] == "S" & titanicDataset$Sex[[i]] == "female")
    print(titanicDataset$Name[[i]])

[1] "Fortune, Mrs. Mark (Mary McDougald)"
[1] "Cornell, Mrs. Robert Clifford (Malvina Helen Lamson)"
[1] "Cavendish, Mrs. Tyrell William (Julia Florence Siegel)"
[1] "Straus, Mrs. Isidor (Rosalie Ida Blun)"
[1] "Howard, Mrs. Benjamin (Ellen Truelove Arman)"
[1] "Crosby, Mrs. Edward Gifford (Catherine Elizabeth Halstead)"
[1] "Brown, Mrs. John Murray (Caroline Lane Lamson)"
[1] "Dodge, Mrs. Washington (Ruth Vidaver)"
[1] "Lines, Mrs. Ernest H (Elizabeth Lindsey James)"
```

**(1)** As it is unclear to which data set you are referring, I use `titanic_test` from `{titanic}`. **(2)** Iterate over all data frame rows (`seq_len(nrow(titanicDataset))`: 1, 2, 3, 4,.... **(3)** Working on complete cases simplifies and systematically biases the analysis. You might change that.
**(4)** Haven't found variable `home.dest`, used `Name` for demonstration purposes. **(5)** Make sure the column names exist and take care of typos. **(6)** In this case, you do not need to write down the `else`-part.

More R-like ways:

```r
subset(titanicDataset, subset = Age >= 50 & Embarked == "S" & Sex == "female", select = Name)
titanicDataset[titanicDataset$Age >= 50 & titanicDataset$Embarked == "S" & titanicDataset$Sex == "female", "Name"]
```

remove `, select = Name` and, respectively, `"Name"` if you are interested in more columns.

Answer (score 0):

For this `for` loop it would be good to ask the question with a sample data set. It isn't a good idea to use integers for named arrays or mixing ways of accessing a dictionary.

First, your are doing a bit `&`, try run the `if` using a logical `&&`.

Assuming your data is an array and you need to access the first element the array is a zero indexed array with 1 element in it then answer is:

```
titanicDataset$home.dest[i-1] // this will get you first first element in the array at position 0

for (i in 1) {
  if (titanicDataset$age[i] >= 50 & (titanicDataset$embarked[i] == "S") && titanicDataset$sex == "female")
  {(print(titanicDataset$home.dest[i]))}
  else if (i == "")
    next
}
```

Another way to do this is with a `for` and a counter or `while`:

```
var i = 0
while (i < 1) {
  if (titanicDataset$age[i] >= 50 & (titanicDataset$embarked[i] == "S") && titanicDataset$sex == "female")
  {(print(titanicDataset$home.dest[i++]))} // this will use i as a 0 and then increment it
    next
  else if (i == "")
    next
}
```